# GIS IMS software

Tags: gis, esri, ogc, opengis

Does any of you know of any GIS IMS capability program that will allow multiple displays of data to be geo linked? For example, when one pans on one view, it should automatically relocate the extent on the corresponding linked viewer.

Comment: You might want to try [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't full understand your question.

Do you want two have two map widgets which are synchronized? Something like that is displayed in http://apps.geomajas.org/showcase-beta/ (indicate layers, google layer in the left menu - you will see that when you drag/zoom one of the maps, the others follow).

If you want one a widget where any operations in that widget change to display of a map, that also sounds pretty easy to do by having a event listener on the one widget which sets the bounds on the map widget. If you want to use Java+GWT, this would be easy using Geomajas.